# Disabling scrolling on Code Mirror element

Tags: scroll, codemirror, react-codemirror

I’m trying to achieve a similar effect on a Code Mirror component that would be achieved by doing overflow: hidden on a div.

In practice this means:

- No visible scroll bars
- When “scroll action” takes place on the editor, the website body moves itself (i.e., impossible to scroll editor relative to the website)

How could I do that?

P.S.

A simple “overflow: hidden” didn’t work because it looks like CodeMirror creates a separate div for vertical scroll bar and horizontal scrollbar. My guess is that javascript is used to handle actual scrolling behavior. Do I need javascript to revert this?

P.S.S.

I'm using `react-codemirror2`, but looking for a general answer and happy to figure out how to execute it within react.

Comment: this might help https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/wvvwJWw

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated Answer

*CSS, where `.editor` is the div wrapping the textarea*:

```
.editor .CodeMirror-scroll {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

/* hide the scrollbars */
.editor .CodeMirror-vscrollbar, .editor .CodeMirror-hscrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

*JS, where `editor` is your codemirror instance*:

```
// does not allow focus within codemirror editor:
editor.setOption('readOnly', 'nocursor');
```

Then you can set your `scrollTop()` position by another editor if need be.

---

**Issues:**

- cannot copy from the editor.
- when selecting content, moving the mouse up and down will cause scroll. ~ going to look for a fix for this.

Comment: Yep, I want the scrolling disabled/frozen completely.

I can hide the scrollbars using the Code Mirror API.

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately, I can still scroll with my touch bar when hovering the editor even with this rule. The CodeMirror editor scrolling is controlled via javascript which is why this may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollbarStyle: null which Completely hides the scroll

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
      lineNumbers: true,
      scrollbarStyle: null
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using react-codemirror2, it accepts `className` prop and preventing scroll can be done via css easily. You should add `max-height` with `height: auto`.

```
 <CodeMirror
   ...
   className={isScrollable ? 'disable-scroll' : ''}
 />

// sample css
 .disable-scroll .CodeMirror {
   max-height: 10rem;
   height: auto;
 }
```